# Big Query : how to retrieve values in field 1 corresponding to field 2

Tags: mysql, sql, select, google-bigquery

I am fairly new to SQL, Big Query

I have a dataset and I want to retrieve values in column 2 corresponding to the values in column 1 if they satisfy certain conditions. I want to know how to do that. I am using Big Query Platform

Example Dataset D :

```
 Col 1 ; Col 2 

   A   ; 1  

   B   ; 2   

   C   ; 3

   D   ; 4

   E   ; 5
```

Query to retrieve values of col1, col2 such that col2 >2

Expected Output :

```
C ; 3

D ; 4 

E ; 5
```

I am using big query platform. 
According to me,

```
SELECT col1,col2
FROM [D]
WHERE col2>2
```

will give col1 and col2 as outputs where col2>2 but the values in col2 may or may not be the ones corresponding to col1.

Am I wrong ? If so, please suggest a query to get necessary output.

Comment: I am HONESTLY unclear on your question. if you have the table described as your input and the expected output being what you want... your query will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a row `A;5`, it won't ever exist in your return. The only time you need to worry about the mismatch is if you're doing a join between one data set of `{A, B, C, D, E}` and another of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. Then every possible combination from `A;1, A;2...` to `...E;4, E;5` would be output, and filtering on `col2 > 2` would produce `A;3, B;3, C;3, ...`, etc. But that isn't how your data is set up in your question, so don't worry. If you wonder how a select query will work, it's usually okay to just run it, unless it will take hours and consume tons of resources and you have a budget... but it seems more like you're doing homework.

Also don't ask for homework help on stack overflow.